# Get Used Binding in IIS log

Tags: iis-7, log-files

I've around 300 domain name in same iis site, when I'm looking the log I cannot determinate which binding is used for each request.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

At least in IIS 7.5 and newer when using the default W3C log format, you can just add the field `Host (cs-host)` to the log fields. Either in the GUI or on the command line:

`%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='yoursitename'].logFile.logExtFileFlags:"Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,ServerIP,Method,UriStem,UriQuery,HttpStatus,Win32Status,TimeTaken,ServerPort,UserAgent,Referer,Host, HttpSubStatus"  /commit:apphost`

Now you can see the hostname in the logs.

I assume this works on IIS 7 as well, but I don't have a 2008 Server anymore to confirm this.